# Sum of first $n$ coefficients of power series expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Consider the coefficients of the following expansion 
$$\frac{\left( e^{c t}-1 \right)^m}{(c \cdot t)^m e^{xt}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n^m(x, c)\frac{t^n}{n!}.$$

Fix any $N,m,c\in\mathbb{N}.$ I would like to get a formula for

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N}A_n^{2m+1}\left( 2m+1,c \right)$$

so that no $A_n^{m}(\cdot,c)$ with $m>1$ appear anymore, i.e. I would like to get a formula like
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N}A_n^{2m+1}\left( 2m+1,c \right)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{M} a_i A_i^1(x(i),c).$$

Do you know if this is possible and how to get there?

edit: It seems that the initial question was to difficult, since I have not got any promising answer. After I have thought about my initial problem some days, I decided to change the question into a more promising one. I hope this is allowed.

Comment: "edit: It seems that the initial question was to difficult, since I have not got any promising answer. After I have thought about my initial problem some days, I decided to change the question into a more promising one." Then what happens with the existing answer? It becomes irrelevant because you changed your mind?

Comment: Yes, it is irrelevant.

Comment: "Yes, it is irrelevant." And how do you feel about this?

Comment: What do you mean by your question?

Comment: That one should not modify substantially a question after some answers are received, obviously.

Comment: I didn't know that. We can change it back. The new question grew out of the initial one and is related to it somehow. Therefore I thought it would be best to do it this way. I'm sorry about thta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some typos.
"$c_1\cdots c_n$"
should be
"$c_1\cdots c_m$"
on both sides.
Also,
on the left,
should $e^{xt}$
be $e^{mxt}$?

Anyway,
I'll play around a little.

From
$\frac{\prod_{n=1}^{m}\left( e^{c_n t}-1 \right)}{c_1\cdots c_n t^m e^{xt}}
=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n^m(x\vert c_1\cdots c_n)\frac{t^n}{n!}
$,
$\prod_{n=1}^{m}\left( e^{c_n t}-1 \right)
=c_1\cdots c_n t^m e^{mxt}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n^m(x\vert c_1\cdots c_n)\frac{t^n}{n!}
$,
or,
letting
$C
=c_1\cdots c_m
$
and eliding the
$c_i$ and the
superscript $m$
on the right,
$\prod_{n=1}^{m}\left(\frac{ e^{c_n t}-1}{te^{xt}} \right)
=C \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}
$.

From the definition of the
Bernoulli polynomials,
$\beta(x, t)
=\frac{te^{xt}}{e^t-1}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}
$,
this becomes

\begin{align}
1
& =C \prod_{n=1}^{m}\left(\frac{te^{xt}}{ e^{c_n t}-1} \right)\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}\\
& =C \prod_{n=1}^{m}\left(\frac1{c_n}\frac{c_nte^{xt}}{ e^{c_n t}-1} \right)\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}\\
& = \prod_{n=1}^{m}\left(\frac{c_nte^{(x/c_n)(c_nt)}}{ e^{c_n t}-1} \right)\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}\\
& = \prod_{n=1}^{m}\beta(c_nt, x/c_n) \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}\\
& = \prod_{n=1}^{m}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} B_k(x/c_n)\frac{(c_nt)^k}{n!}\right)\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}.
\end{align}.

I don't know where to go from here.
Maybe try $m=2$ to see if that suggests anything, or differentiate.

Good luck.